# Are questions of the type “What plugin is this?” allowed?

Tags: discussion

Often times, one finds resources, plugins, scripts or libraries on websites that one would like to identify. For example, would a question like this be acceptable:

"I found this gallery on this website: *website here*. Can anyone tell me what plugin this is?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, sorry, these questions are [Guessing Games](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/). They are not helpful for anyone, and their answers would be mostly just plain links. All links die eventually – not the content we want to collect here.